# Find recurrence relation of $T(n)=2T\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor\right)+\log(n)$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

Sorry about the formatting of the title I'm not sure of the codes to make it look better.

I need to find the recurrence relation of the following:

> $$T(0) = 1$$
>
> $$T(n) = 2T\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor\right)+\log(n)$$

I assume this is going to be done via substitution method and through induction, but I have no idea how to set it up/solve it.

The answer is $T(n)=\theta\left(\log\,n \cdot\log\log\,n\right)$

Comment: What do you mean by $\theta$? (Is it about asymptotic growth?) - Also, note that if we let $f(n) = e^{T(n)}$, we get the reccurence as $f(n) = nf(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)^2$.

Comment: Yeah, it is about asymptotic growth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the exponential tower
one higher,
let $n = 2^{2^m}$.
Then
$\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor
=\lfloor \sqrt{2^{2^m}} \rfloor
=\lfloor 2^{2^{m-1}} \rfloor
$
and
$\log n
=\log 2^{2^m}
= 2^m
$.

The recurrence becomes
$T(2^{2^m})
=2T(2^{2^{m-1}})+2^m
$.

Let
$S(m)
=T(2^{2^m})
$.
Then
$S(m)
=2S(m-1)+2^ m
$
or,
dividing by
$2^m$,
$2^{-m}S(m)
=2^{-(m-1)}S(m-1)+1
$.
Letting
$2^{-m}S(m)
=U(m)
$,
$U(m) 
=U(m-1)+1
$.

Summing,
$U(m) = m$
so
$S(m)
=m2^m
$.

Finally,
$T(m)
=S(\log \log m)
=(\log \log m)2^{\log \log m}
=\log m \log \log m
$.

This avoids
appealing to a
"well known recurrence".

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $n = 2^m$. The recurrence becomes
$$
T(2^m) = 2\,T(2^{m/2}) + m
$$
(assuming logs to the base 2). Then let $T(2^m) = S(m)$, giving us the recurrence
$$
S(m) = 2\,S(m/2)+m
$$
This is a well-known recurrence with solution $S(m) = \Theta(m\log m)$, from which we can conclude (since $\log n = m$), $T(n) = \Theta(\log n\,\log\log n)$. Now just fill in the details.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, thanks!